# Absolutely lost with RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am pretty new to C# and want to create a REST Get request with Basic auth.
I'm using RestSharp but i can't find a proper working full example.
This is my code:

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;


namespace HttpClientAPP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://data.myhost.de");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "xxxx");



            var request = new RestRequest("resource",Method.Get);

            client.ExecuteGetAsync(request).Wait();
            
            Console.WriteLine("as");
        }
    }
}
```

This is thejson answer I expect and i want to parse it to use the data to store it in a MYSQL DB:

```
    {"info": [
      {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://data.myhost.de/zfa-values/{zfaId}",
      "description": "Get a ZFA value by id"
   },
      {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://data.myhost.de/zfa-values",
      "description": "Get a list of available ZFA values"
   },
      {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://data.myhost.de/new-zfa-values",
      "description": "Get a list of available ZFA values which have not been viewed yet"
   },
      {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://data.myhost.de/",
      "description": "Get a list of api endpoints"
   }
]}
```

How do I parse the json response?

Comment: Does this API you're using publish a swagger/openapi spec?

Comment: Why not use `client.GetJsonAsync<TModel>(request)` and have RestSharp automatically deserialise the JSON to a known model type (TModel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://restsharp.dev/v107/#recommended-usage there is some guidance (but at time of writing this answer I think it might have a typo)

Get docs says:

```
public class GitHubClient {
    readonly RestClient _client;

    public GitHubClient() {
        _client = new RestClient("https://api.github.com/")
            .AddDefaultHeader(KnownHeaders.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    }

    public Task<GitHubRepo[]> GetRepos()
        => _client.GetAsync<GitHubRepo[]>("users/aspnet/repos");
                   ^^^^^^^^
        //note: I think this should be GetJsonAsync
}
```

Post docs says:

```
var request = new MyRequest { Data = "foo" };
var response = await _client.PostAsync<MyRequest, MyResponse>(request, cancellationToken);
                             ^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^
        //note: i think this should be PostJsonAsync      and the first arg should be a string url path
```

You have classes that represent the json you send/get back, and RestSharp will de/serialize them for you. If you want some help making classes from JSON, take a look at services like http://app.QuickType.io - you paste your json and you get representative classes. The online generators are usually a bit more sophisticated in terms of what they interpret/the attributes they decorate with. Pasting your json into QT gives (you can choose a better name than SomeRoot):

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class SomeRoot
    {
        [JsonProperty("info")]
        public Info[] Info { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Info
    {
        [JsonProperty("method")]
        public string Method { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SomeRoot
    {
        public static SomeRoot FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeRoot>(json, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this SomeRoot self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace HttpClientAPP
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://data.myhost.de");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "xxxx");

            var res = await client.GetJsonAsync<SomeRoot>("");

            Console.ReadLine(); //prevent exit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to I add the basic auth in this example?

Comment: I tweaked the example; I don't have the password so I couldn't test it

Comment: Here "var res = await client.GetAsync<Welcome>("");" it says that the converison from string to RestSharp.RestRequest isn't possible, so i cant execute it

Comment: Seems a mistake in their docs, and the call should be GetJsonAsync

Comment: Seems to be working, awesome! Ty very much

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use newtosoft json nuget package:
Docs: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Example:

```
class ApiEndpoint{
 public string Method {get;set;} // or you can use enum 
 public string Url {get;set;} 
 public string Description {get;set;} 
}
// some logic
public void Fetch()
{
   var client = new RestClient("https://data.myhost.de");
   client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "xxxx");

   var request = new RestRequest("resource",Method.Get);
   var response = client.Get(request);
   // read response as json
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<ApiEndpoint>>(response);
   // now json will have structure in your example
}
```

2. Other way is to add swagger gen for you server, get openapi.json and then generate sharp client using nswag
   https://blog.logrocket.com/generate-typescript-csharp-clients-nswag-api/

Comment: Ooof, so manual; RestSharp will do your deser; just tell it what type you're expecting in response - you don't need to pull a string and then tell newtonsoft to deser it. You've also forgotten to give newtonsoft the json?

Comment: var response = client.Get(request); doesnt work. It says that there is no definition for Get. I could use GetAsync, but when i use it,  there is another error that says that "response is not null". As I said, i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @CaiusJard to be honest, i've never worked with this before. I'm trying to get a minimal example to work so i can study it and alternate things to learn from it.

I'm just trying to get a working simple program